# Yum fails to respect version requirements for package

Tags: yum, dependencies, oracle-linux

I have a problem using yum to resolve dependencies for my project, which consists of multiple RPMs that we build ourselves. I have built an RPM with:

```
Requires: Database-devel = 1.0.0
```

But when I run:

```
$ yum deplist Release/ConfigLoader-devel-4.0.1-0.191128.123053.g83eb.b.d.el7.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: epel.besthosting.ua
package: ConfigLoader-devel.x86_64 4.0.1-0.191128.123053.g83eb.b.d.el7
  dependency: /bin/sh
   provider: bash.x86_64 4.2.46-31.el7
  dependency: Database-devel = 1.0.0
   provider: Database-devel.x86_64 2.0.0-0.191126.123742.gb769.r
```

It says that the provider of that dependency (the last line) has version 2.0.0. The following additional information confirms that the versions for the Database-devel package are set up correctly in the yum repo, and that there's a 1.0.0 version available for yum to select:

```
$ yum info Database-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: epel.besthosting.ua
Available Packages
Name        : Database-devel
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.0.0
Release     : 0.191126.123742.gb769.r
Size        : 13 k
Repo        : localrepo-oel7


$ yum info Database-devel-1.0.0-1
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: epel.besthosting.ua
Available Packages
Name        : Database-devel
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.0.0
Release     : 1
Size        : 13 k
Repo        : localrepo-oel7
```

The issue is that when I try to install the ConfigLoader-devel RPM, it tries to pull down the Database-devel 2.0.0 package and install it, which breaks my build.

My yum version is:

```
$ yum --version
3.4.3
  Installed: rpm-4.11.3-35.el7.x86_64 at 2019-05-21 13:14
  Built    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org> at 2018-10-30 19:27
  Committed: Pavlina Moravcova Varekova <pmoravco@redhat.com> at 2018-06-19

  Installed: yum-3.4.3-161.0.1.el7.noarch at 2019-06-05 11:27
  Built    : None at 2018-11-01 10:10
  Committed: EL Errata <el-errata_ww@oracle.com> at 2018-10-31

  Installed: yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.31-50.el7.noarch at 2019-05-21 13:15
  Built    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org> at 2018-10-30 22:58
  Committed: Michal Domonkos <mdomonko@redhat.com> at 2018-08-24
```

How can I diagnose this further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your package `Database-devel` provides `Database-devel`. You can check this like this:

```
rpm -q Database-devel --provides
```

it should say something like this:

```
Database-devel = 2.0.0-0
```

if it says also:

```
Database-devel
```

without version number, then this means for `rpm` and thus for `yum` that it provides all versions of `Database-devel`, including version 1.0.0.

You should remove the line

```
Provides: Database-devel
```

from your spec file. Each package automatically provides its own name and version.

Comment: You were totally correct, the Database-devel package had a `Provides: Database-devel` in it. I'm not sure how you knew that, but good catch! Thanks very much!

Comment: @Obiphil I do a lot of rpm packaging, I've seen quite some things, but thanks :)